# Trying to find index of ObjectId in Mongo DB with indexOf

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, indexof

I am trying to get the index of a specific ObjectId. I am getting -1, when trying to get the correct Id. What am I doing wrong?

```
console.log("Array of Id's ", userResult[0].reservations)
var idFetch = JSON.stringify(forIter[i]._id)
console.log("ID ", idFetch)
var indexOfUserReservationCondition = userResult[0].reservations.indexOf(idFetch)
console.log("INDEX ", indexOfUserReservationCondition)
```

> Array of Id's  [ '60b4e7ba02edf04a840d2fb8', '60bdf9ba1752a750e4b57115' ]

> ID  "60bdf9ba1752a750e4b57115"

> INDEX -1

Answer (score 0):

```js
let userResult = [{ "reservations": ['60b4e7ba02edf04a840d2fb8', '60bdf9ba1752a750e4b57115'] }]

console.log("Array of Id's ", userResult[0].reservations)

var idFetch = '60b4e7ba02edf04a840d2fb8'

var indexOfUserReservationCondition = userResult[0].reservations.indexOf(idFetch)
console.log("INDEX ", indexOfUserReservationCondition)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `JSON.stringify()`: As you can see in the `console.log` of the ID, the variable `idFetch` is not, as you expect, the string `'60bdf9ba1752a750e4b57115'`, but instead the string `'"60bdf9ba1752a750e4b57115"'`. IndexOf cannot find the `idFetch` and therefore returns `-1`.

```
var idFetch = forIter[i]._id.toString();
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that was my first try and it did not work like that. That's why I went with **JSON.stringify()** around the second time.

Comment: JSON.stringify() is the wrong way since it adds the quotation marks. Does `forIter[i]._id.toString()` work?

Comment: This one worked and thanks very much for the help!